# Ironpython or Tricks?

Tags: ironpython

I'm writing a project in C#, I need to add an exiting project written in python.
The first and simply thing that came to my mind is to use Ironpython and access the python as if he was .net code.

But somehow it's not easy as I thought, an exception follows one eachother (and it has work flawless in native python).
So my questions is simply, shall I write a wrapper to the main methods and execute them like cmd script?
Is there another simle python for .net alternative?
Or maybe I totally misunderstand something with Ironpython?
I searched in google but all topics I saw was outdated.
Is there any pattern for these cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, there is no alternative python for .net than ironpython. I would start with breaking down the old projects to small peaces and try to make them work. Do you have any specific points that did not work? If you found some errors, just create an issue on the ironpython github repository. In my point of view, creating some wrapper is not the best way, try to make it work by going step by step and see if it is a possible solution for you.

Comment: Tnx for answering, I did worked with Ironpython in the past, in the current proj, I didn't even succedd to INSTALL the module I wanted to work with. Using wrappers was mch easier :-), maybe not the best, but still.

Comment: Good you found a solution. You may write an answer or should i edit my post?